# No item exists at http://xxxx/Common/Forms/EditForm.aspx It may have been deleted or renamed by another user

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, item-added, item-level-permissions

When I am trying to apply an item level permissions for a uploaded document in my document library am getting the error:

> No item exists at http://xxxx/Common/Forms/EditForm.aspx?Mode=Upload&CheckInComment=&ID=170&RootFolder=/Common/KnowledgeDocuments&IsDlg=1.  It may have been deleted or renamed by another user

am able to upload the document but am getting this ugly yellow error!

> No item exists at http://xxxx/Common/Forms/EditForm.aspx It may have
>   been deleted or renamed by another user

[image: eror-inuplaodingadocinfolder1]

```
        List<String> objlistofGroupNames = new List<string>();

        SPListItemCollection pconfigILPItemCollection = null;
        try
        {
            SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
            {
                SPSite CurrentSite = new SPSite(paramProperties.SiteId);
                SPWeb CurrentWeb = 
      CurrentSite.OpenWeb(paramProperties.RelativeWebUrl);
                CurrentWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                SPList configCurrentList = 
  CurrentWeb.Lists.TryGetList(NPDListNames.ITEMLEVELPERMISSIONSLIST);

                SPQuery objquery = new SPQuery();

                foreach (SPListItem singleItemConfigList in 
          configCurrentList.Items)
                      {
                      if (singleItemConfigList != null && 
              singleItemConfigList.ListItems.Count > 0)
                      {
                        string strEntityConfigList = 
              singleItemConfigList["Entity"].ToString();  //Common|Others

      if (!pCurrentListItem.HasUniqueRoleAssignments)
                                        {
                 pCurrentListItem.BreakRoleInheritance(false);
                        CurrentWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
          SPRoleAssignmentCollection SPRoleAssColn = 
                  pCurrentListItem.RoleAssignments;
                                            for (int i = SPRoleAssColn.Count 
                              - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            SPRoleAssignment roleAssignmentSingle = SPRoleAssColn[i];
           System.Type t = roleAssignmentSingle.Member.GetType();
                                                //    continue;
                                                //if (roleAssignmentSingle.Member.LoginName == properties.UserLoginName)
                                                //   continue; 
                  SHAREPOINT\\system
                                               //if 
          (roleAssignmentSingle.Member.LoginName != "SHAREPOINT\\system" ||  
         roleAssignmentSingle.Member.ID != npdadminSPGroup.ID || 
        roleAssignmentSingle.Member.LoginName != 
              paramProperties.UserLoginName)
                                              if 
              (roleAssignmentSingle.Member.Name != "System Account" && 
              roleAssignmentSingle.Member.LoginName != 
                          paramProperties.UserLoginName)
                  {
                   if (t.Name == "SPGroup" || t.Name == "SPUser")
                         sPRoleAssColn.Remove(i);                                                    
                     }                        
 }

                          try
                          {
                           if 
          (!singlestrReadILPGroupName.ToLower().Contains("creator") && 
              !string.IsNullOrEmpty(singlestrReadILPGroupName))  //non-
           //author  /sp group permissions
                {
             SPGroup singleSPGroup = 
              pCurrentWeb.SiteGroups[singlestrReadILPGroupName];
       SPRoleAssignment mroleAssignmentEditNoDelILP = new 
       SPRoleAssignment(singleSPGroup);
      SPRoleDefinition mroleDefinitionEditNoDelILP = 
           pCurrentWeb.RoleDefinitions["NPD ReadILP"];

        mroleAssignmentEditNoDelILP.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add(
         mroleDefinitionEditNoDelILP);
       pCurrentListItem.RoleAssignments.Add
          (mroleAssignmentEditNoDelILP);
   singlestrReadILPGroupName.ToLower().Contains("creator") && 
       !string.IsNullOrEmpty(singlestrReadILPGroupName)) ///author 
        //permissions <p>
        at last am doing  <p>
             pCurrentListItem.SystemUpdate(false);
```

Please understand that, my document library's versioning settings are set to  **Create Major Versions** [ NOT MINOR VERSIONS] 
 and Require document to be checked out is set to **NO**

Comment: Is it an event receiver? right? which event are you using? Is it item added?!

Comment: Yes of course, its an item eventreceiver  on a doc lib, with itemadded ,itemupdated event handlers.

Comment: where this code specifically  ? in itemadded  or itemupdated

Comment: its added in itmadded() event handler . and similar code been added with few changes but with a different set of permissions [ different sp groups ] on the itemupdated event handler . also would like to  mention that,  i have created custom permissions levels  as well, like contributenodelete, DesignWithoutEditItems etc . these permissions were applied to the sp groups when item is updated

Comment: Try to add your code (set document permission) only at `ItemUpdated` or `ItemUpdating` to can catch the document properties, then set its permission! hope it working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to debug your event receiver and you will note that this error raised from the `itemAdded` event, because the metadata is not available in the `ItemAdded`event and this cause

> No item exists. It may have been deleted or renamed by another user

So Make sure that you have added your code (set document permission) only at `ItemUpdated` or `ItemUpdating` to can catch the document properties, then set its permission!

Comment: unfortunately there are no metadata - custom fields available or i have created in my doc lib. its plain doc lib, with default columns - modfiied, modified by, created etc. end user will simply add the document for sharing with others and other group members will be getting the read/contributenodelete permissions

Comment: I have tested with itemupdated method ONLY, based on your suggestion , and it  seems working for 2 docu libs. i am having soem 14 doc libs with item level permissions applied with several different groups having contribute, edit, read permissions. am testing again n with multiple doc libs . if there exists any issues , will update here,

Comment: Great job :) , of course, updating me in case, you face related issue!

Comment: it would be great , if you can help me, by spending few minutes for some of the other doubts i have raised few minutes before. related to search, re-index the list/doclib . :-)

Comment: Sure, provide me the Quest URL, Hope I can help!

Comment: M.Qassas : thanks for your reply. Here is the link,for one of the questions i have requested and am unable to proceed :  related to adv,search results: 
      https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/218509/hide-managed-property-of-property-restrictions-from-the-adv-search-results