# Hide managed property of property restrictions from the adv.search results

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, advanced-search

Is there any way / is it possible to hide the **owstext** name/property of search keyword from advanced search results?

It may create a  confusion in end-user's mind, like what this "owstext" 
funda is ? When I search for a  keyword from a  advanced property restrictions dropdown and click on search, am able to get search results but these advanced property thats associated with managed property is also populated/displayed in the  search box.

How to hide this, from end user? 
[image: hide-owstext-word-managed-property]

From the above image, i need to remove the DIVISIONOWSTEXT from the search box.